# Mircrosoft Intunes SSO - iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, azure, intune

I am developing one iOS and one Android app and I need to implement SSO - Single Sign-On feature in both.

**I have 'Company Portal' - Microsoft Intunes app installed already on my device.**

Is it possible to use Intunes Login for my application? SO that I can skip independent login flow for my applications.

Please suggest solution for both platforms (iOS/Android)

I also tried integrating Azure Ad Sdk, but still my app ask for Login individually and not accepting/detecting Intunes App login, like **Microsoft One Drive**

Comment: I don't believe you can since the Microsoft apps can share a keychain but your app can't access that shared keychain, so you cannot access the existing token.  Your app will need to go through the OAuth authentication process, but if your user has already authenticated this should be pre-populated with their identity.

Comment: That doesn’t really mean anything. The outlook developers could have chosen not to use the shared keychain while the OneDrive developers could. You don’t have the option.

Comment: Seems to be. However do you have any pointer for my use case.

Comment: @prasadnikumbh - did you got solution for this? I am looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Authenticator App broker for your solution.

1. User has to be install 'Microsoft Authenticator App'  from App store.
2. Then Install 'Intune Company Portal' app
3. Try to login in Intune Company App, it will redirect to the Broker app for sign-in.
4. When user successfully logged in with Comapny app, then try to sign-in with your own app (Broker setting need to be do in app code).
5. Your app will redirect to Broker app for sign-in, and in broker app user has to be click/choose stored email id reference to auto sign-in without asking any password.

[Check tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-v1-enable-sso-ios#step-1-enable-broker-mode-in-your-application)